# Get all contacts from dual sim

Tags: android-contacts, dual-sim

I want to get all contacts of both sims in android dual sim

As far as I know content uri of sim main (sim1) contacts is content://icc/adn

But i can't get contacts from sim2. I don't know content uri of sim2.

Can anyone help me please!!?

Thanks in Advance